# UTC time difference in ReactJs application and Python server

Tags: python, reactjs, python-3.x, websocket

I am calculating UTC time in reactjs application as

```
const currentTime = Date.now()
```

Sending this time to backend python server over websocket request where I am calculating UTC time as

```
dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
utc_timestamp = dt.timestamp()*1000 #in milliseconds.
```

`int(utc_timestamp * 1000) - int(data["timestamp"])` should always be positive but sometimes it is negative. I am trying to calculate one way latency.
Is there a way to calculate the platform independent time in ReactJs application and Python server?

The request sent from reactjs at UTC time 1610043735201 and when it received in Python UTC time was 1610043734351.

Reactjs UTC time 1610043735295  Python UTC time 1610043734420

Reactjs UTC time 1610043734896 Python UTC time 1610043734037

Comment: Maybe the browser reduced time precision: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now#Reduced_time_precision

Comment: I use chrome only, is there a way to consider the precision to calculate time.

Comment: I tried reproducing this issue with node.js as a backend with no success (in all major browsers). All time diffs are greater than 0. Can you provide a full example, where you have that issue?